# why the result of blob detection does not change after the change of parameters?

Tags: python, opencv, blob

I got the program of blob detection in the following website: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

It is quiet useful,but i found nothing change in the result after i change the parameters value.
like: even i set the parameter of color to 255(it is used to detect lighter blobs), the dark blobs still can be detected. Also, after i change the value of minimum area, the smallest blob also can be detected.

it seems nothing changes,the result is always like the following one:
[the result of blob detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELRYc.jpg)
Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("blob.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10;    # the graylevel of images
params.maxThreshold = 200;

params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 255

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = False
params.minArea = 10000

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change parameters but they are not used by the detector. Set them and then set up the detector:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = cv2.imread('blob.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10    # the graylevel of images
params.maxThreshold = 200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 1500

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(
    im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
    cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow('Keypoints', im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Note: you have to use `True` for `params.filterByArea` if you want this parameter to be used and to not end on a segfault.